# shell_exec chmod on directories

Tags: php, chmod

I'm calling a PHP file from the browser which is searching for some sub-directories and changing their permissions to 777 using chmod. The process runs under user 'www-data'
I've (temporarily!!) allowed the 'www-data' to have the correct rights in the /etc/sudoers file, but still can't get the permissions to change.

```
<?php
shell_exec("find /home/path -type d -name Directory_name_to_search_for -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 777");
?>
```

Is this something to do with where I'm calling sudo?

Comment: did you check if `find` is actually finding anything?

Comment: Yes - From the command line it prints out a long list of the directory names, but with no spaces inbetween.

Comment: to be expected, `print0` forces `find` to use null (`\0`) as the inter-filename separator, which xargs uses in `-0` mode, so that spaces in filenames don't get treated as filename separators. since find is working, then something' wonky with your sudo setup.

Comment: OK - sudo setup was indeed incorrect - thank you very much all fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

a line break at the beginning of the output seemed to prevent shell_exec printing anything else. Hope this saves someone else an hour or two.

```
<?php
shell_exec("find /home/path -type d -name Directory_name_to_search_for -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 777 2>&1");
?>
```

> **2>&1**

Comment: OK - the logs give me this; `COMMAND=/bin/chmod 777 /home/dropbox/home/path/match_1/Directory_name_to_search_for /home/path/match_2/Directory_name_to_search_for` etc etc. All of the directories exist, so the find bit works, but the output is broken up only by spaces.

Comment: Working now - Youssef got me there and Marc B thank you.